# Too many open files - Web-logic Exception

Tags: java, soap, wsdl, weblogic, dozer

I'm using DozerMapper for one of my REST services that are calling through a service registry some SOAP web services. Now the weird part is that i'm getting this

> ```
> Error on retrieving service client from pool (*.*.ws.cal.ServiceTargetException) Error on reading WSDL at:
> ```
>
> http://10.32.129.61:9002/*/ReferenceDataRetrievalBAS?WSDL
>   (*.*.*.ws.cal.ServiceTargetException) WSDLException:
>   faultCode=PARSER_ERROR: Failed to read wsdl file at:
>   "http://10.32.129.61:9002/*/ReferenceDataRetrievalBAS?WSDL", caused
>   by: java.net.SocketException.: java.net.SocketException: Too many open
>   files (oracle.j2ee.ws.wsdl.LocalizedWSDLException) Too many open files
>   (java.net.SocketException)

This Weblogic error message seems to be common with a lot of solutions most of them has to do with file descriptors in OS (i'm using RHEL 7 - 3.10.0-327.el7.x86_64). Though i have tried all the above but the error persist. ulimit -n equals to 65536 (maximum)

Any suggestion or help? Maybe it has to do with Dozer?